# Using GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 for textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a method for loading texture into OpenGL:

```
bool AndroidGraphicsManager::setTexture(
    UINT& id, UCHAR* image, UINT width, UINT height,
    bool wrapURepeat, bool wrapVRepeat, bool useMipmaps)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
        width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) image);
    int minFilter = GL_LINEAR;

    if (useMipmaps) {
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        minFilter = GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST;
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    int wrap_u = wrapURepeat ?
        GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    int wrap_v = wrapVRepeat ?
        GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE;
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrap_u);
    glTexParameteri(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, wrap_v);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return !checkGLError("Loading texture.");
}
```

This works fine. I load texture using libpng. This gives me array of unsigned chars. Then I pass this array to my method specified above. Pictures are 32bit, so I assume in UCHAR array each UCHAR contains single color component and four UCHARs make up one pixel. I wanted to try using 16 bit textures. I changed GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4. But apparently this isn't enough because it gives me this result:
[image]
What else do I need to change to be able to properly display 16 bit textures?

**[EDIT]** As @DatenWolf suggested I tried using this code:

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA4,
    width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, (GLvoid*) image);
```

I used it on Linux version of my engine, but the result was the exact same as in previous android screenshot. So is it safe to assume that the problem is with libpng and the way it produces my UCHAR array?

**[EDIT2]** So I finally managed to compress 32bit texture to 16bit.
All I needed was a simple iteration through 32bit texture data and a few bitshifting operations to compress 32 bits into 16.

```
void* rgba8888ToRgba4444(void* in, int size) {
    int pixelCount = size / 4;
    ULONG* input = static_cast<ULONG*>(in);
    USHORT* output = new USHORT[pixelCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
        ULONG pixel = input[i];
        // Unpack the source data as 8 bit values
        UINT r = pixel & 0xff;
        UINT g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        UINT b = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        UINT a = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
        // Convert to 4 bit vales
        r >>= 4; g >>= 4; b >>= 4; a >>= 4;
        output[i] = r << 12 | g << 8 | b << 4 | a;
    }
    return static_cast<void*>(output);
}
```

I thought that for mobile device this would yield a performance increase, but unfortunately I saw no gain in performance on Galaxy SIII.
[image]

Comment: If you're using some kind of image library such as devil then that might be able to supply you with the  texture data on the format you need.

Comment: "*This works fine.*" I can't imagine how that could possibly "work fine". You're using `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` with `GL_RGBA`. That means the pixel data you're providing is one short *per color component*. Which doesn't match the actual pixel data you're providing (one byte per color component).

Comment: Nicol, sorry, when I copied the code It had GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 written and I manually wrote GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT and ofcourse I made a mistake, the original code uses GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would probably be to use an image library like [devil](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) for this kind of thing.

But if you want to convert the image data you have you get from libpbg you can do something similar to the code below.

Keep in mind that you trade size for speed when doing this.

```
struct Color {
unsigned char r:4;
unsigned char g:4;
unsigned char b:4;
unsigned char a:4;
};

float factor = 16 / 255;

Color colors[imgWidth*imgHeight];

for(int i = 0; i < imgWidth*imgHeight; ++i)
{
    colors[i].r = image[i*4]*factor;
    colors[i].g = image[i*4+1]*factor;
    colors[i].b = image[i*4+2]*factor;
    colors[i].a = image[i*4+3]*factor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But apparently this isn't enough

The token you've changed tells OpenGL the format of the data in the array passed to it. So you have to adjust that as well. However OpenGL may convert it into any internal format it desires, since you didn't force it into a particular format. That's what the internal format parameter is for (which works independently on the external data type). So if you want to have internally 16 bits resolution you must change the internal format parameter to `GL_RGBA4`. The data may remain in 8 bits per pixel format. So in your case

```
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA4,
    width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
    …, (GLvoid*) image);
```

The type parameter must match the layout of your data. If you've got originally 8 bits per pixel then GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. But if it's prepackaged RGBA in ushorts nibbles then GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4

Comment: He's asking about OpenGL *ES*, which works *very differently* in this regard from OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Oh, thank you. I did open the question from the OpenGL tagged question selection, so my mind was in "regular" OpenGL mode.